# CSS grid items with even gutters and a full width grid

Tags: css, grid, margins

I'm working on a layout that contains a grid like layout within it to show off a set of offers. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Objective]

My problem is I cannot seem to get even and flushed gutters within this grid. Here's what I have so far:

[image: Current Result]

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div><img src="images/welcomeBanner.jpg"></div>
    <div class="offers">
        <img class="offer" src="images/offer1.jpg">
        <img class="offer" src="images/offer2.jpg">
        <img class="offer" src="images/offerX.jpg">
        <img class="offer" src="images/offerX.jpg">
        <img class="offer" src="images/offerX.jpg">
        <img class="offer" src="images/offerX.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#content div#main div.offers img.offer{ padding-top:20px; padding-right: 20px; }
```

I am using `padding-right:20px;` on each of these offer items (`img.offer`). Since these offers are all inline, I cannot seem to get each row to flush with the right side of this main column (align with the right side of the larger banner with the hands).

I would love to achieve this with pure CSS, but I'm coming to the realization that might not happen. I would try `:nth-child(3n)`, but the lack of IE support is a deal breaker for me.

I have no means of using a server side processor to do some math on the number of grid items. I recognize that I may just want to use javascript or jquery to do this math, but I wanted to reach out to see if anyone had any other suggestions.

TLDR: Help me get even gutters and a full width grid.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: 'http://www.thebrightlines.com/2010/01/04/alternative-for-nth-of-type-and-nth-child/' an alternative for IE

Comment: Thanks @ashley! This gets me a little closer. I just need to figure out the right combination.

Comment: It was in the right direction until I realized it wouldn't repeat, and would only target one specific element. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the width of your container is, but this may help:

```
.offer {
    /* some stuff */
    padding-right: 25px; /* You have to find a good value */
}
.offer:nth-child(3n) {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

If you don't want to use `nth-child()` you can alternatively give every 3rd image (.offer) an additional class.

Comment: Since I could not find any CSS only solutions, I've reverted to just slapping classes on each 3rd item. Thanks for your nth-child(3n) suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `img.offer:nth-child(3n) { padding-right: 0; }` this will get rid of the padding on the right of every 3rd img